# How can I use a HAML view as a javascript template in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I am using haml for creating views in rails. I want some of these views to also be available as javascript templates. What is the best way to do that without repeating myself?

I was hoping I can do something like this:

Create a haml view, e.g.

`app/views/my_view.html.haml`

and create a js template as:

`app/assets/templates/my_view.js`

And inside the js template, having something like:

```
//= Rails.views.render('my_view')
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: What do you mean? You want to render this javascript into a haml view?

Comment: I have my views in haml under app/views. I want to use some of them as JS templates as well. But I dont want to copy paste code. I was wondering if there is a way to create a js template that just reads the contents of the haml in the view folder.

Comment: It sounds like you want partials.  You can create anything you want to, including partials and pass them values to fill in the blanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use haml in a javascript thing if you want by putting it in a some_file.js.haml file.

For example, you can use .js.haml files as replacements for the js.erb files that might be used in a javascript call back to mess around with the page.